# How can I recover source overwritten by a bad compile command?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I had written a source code of C++ and complied it with the same name using the following command line.

**For example:**

```
c++ source-code.cpp -o source-code.cpp
```

Now my source code has been replaced by the executable program.**Is there any way to retrieve my source-code.**
I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure if there is any way to undo what I've done.

Comment: Oh Myyy.. This is a great example of why we use source control.

Comment: Voting to move to super-user, since this is OT for SO.  I do feel for ya Pavitar.

Comment: @JoshD: Source control may not have helped in the situation where you check out, make a hundred changes, then compile to test before checking in (rule number 1: never break the build). What I long for are the days of VMS, where every file was versioned whenever it changed, and you could just back up one version to recover the source.

Comment: @paxdiablo: very true. In that case, use a text editor that automatically makes backup in .bak files on each save :)  Journaling file systems seem to be coming into style, which kinda do what you've said. I think apple computers have just that capability.

Comment: unmount filesystem or shut down your computer right away!

Comment: @paxdiablo: That is why you have development branches, which you merge back once your changes got stable. (Ahem. That's also why you have Makefiles with tested-good compiler statements...)

Comment: @JoshD: Journaling filesystems and versioning file systems are separate concepts. Journaling is about crash recovery, versioning about keeping old revisions. Some journaling FS even go out of their way to *delete* old, stale data so it cannot come back after a crash...

Comment: @paxdiablo: AJC Active Backup will do what you want.

Comment: This is why files should be moved to trash instead of blindly `rm`ing them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Probably not, try source control?

---

You might be lucky enough to have an editor open or a terminal window with scrollback.

And in the locking-the-barn-door-after-the-horse-has-bolted department, a good development practice even when working on toy programs is to use source code control.

Using either ***[git](http://git-scm.com/)*** or ***[hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)***, you can do

```
$ hg init
$ hg add source.cpp
$ hg commit -m 'change' source.cpp
$ # edit here, and you can optionally revert to the original
$ hg commit -m 'change' source.cpp
$ # now if you clobber it you can go back to one of the previous revisions
```

Answer (score 7):

The option `-o` specifies the output file, that is why the source code was overwritten.

You should have used

```
c++ source-code.cpp -o executable-name
```

As for retrieving the **original** source from the compiled file: no you cannot. You could disassemble it (so get an assembly version of your program) and I'm sure there is some little program out there that will rewrite some "C++ style" code from it, but that will never be like your original code as more than one instruction in C++ may correspond to the same machine code.

Comment: You can just use: "g++ filename.cpp" and the run with "./a.out". You can disassemble using IDAPro (or some other powerful disassembler) from which you can recover the code.

Comment: @jase21: sure, but probably `a.out` is not the best filename ever :). IDAPro will not recover the ORIGINAL code anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Which editor did you use. Most probably there might be source-code.cpp~ backup file if you are using Vim or something.

Comment: @jase21 -- I was using Vi editor. thankyou

Comment: @Pavitar So there definitely will be a backup. Did you find it?

Comment: NO.I guess Vi editor doesn't create a backup.

Comment: Check this page on how to keep incremental backups in Vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_incremental_backups_of_edited_files

Answer (score 2):

oops ... you are out of luck.

> First of all: Immediately unmount the
>   file system the deleted file was
>   located on. This minimizes the risk
>   that the data of the deleted file are
>   overwritten while taking steps to
>   recover them. **All data written to
>   the file system containing the deleted
>   file - either by you or by any other
>   process running on your machine -
>   might overwrite some of the data you
>   want to recover!**

more here: http://e2undel.sourceforge.net/recovery-howto.html

Answer (score 2):

Try some disk recovering tool maybe the new file wasn't written on the same blocks as the original one. I am just thinking out loud here, but its better that you gave this a shot. Btw which editor are you using? Have you checked if your editor creates an automatic backup of every file?

Answer (score 1):

In the highly unlikely event that you haven't closed your vi session yet, open a new terminal and look for a `.source-code.cpp.swp` file in the same folder. Remember that files starting with a period are not listed by `ls` command by default; use `ls -A` to see them.

The last line of the `.swp` file would have the text from your original file before being corrupted by mal-compilation.

My original file `test.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
        cout << "Let us C";
}
```

The last part of my `.test.cpp.swp` (in this case, it contained a single huge line).

```
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
@^@^@^cout << "Let us C";^@   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;^@{^@int main()^@^@using namespace std;^@#i    nclude <iostream>^@
```

The `.swp` file get deleted once you close the vi session; so if you've already closed it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

no, unless you can undo your action through Linux, your source code is lost. You probably should have compiled it to a different name.

You cannot reverse-compile your source code.

Comment: Decompilation is possible, but it won't return the original source code.

Comment: It will likely make little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say it's impossible. The FBI can probably get some portion of it back with a huge heaping helping of luck. But since your executable is certainly larger than your source, you've overwritten all of it.

This is one reason why you should use a version control system.
[Check out SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As @jase21 mentioned, if you'd used `vim` or `gedit`, there'll be a `source.cpp~` file which contains a backup.

`emacs` will have a `#source.cpp#` file.

What text editor did you use? On a lighter note, how many lines of code lost?